# Should I violate the S in SOLID or should I violate the DRY Principle?

Tags: c#, dry, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I had a method for sending GET requests like this:

```
private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
    }
    catch // This method crashes if only one json "record" is found - try this:
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(GetScalarVal(uri));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

...I altered it to deal with POST requests by wedging this between the assignments to webRequest and webResponse:

```
if (uri.ToUpper().Contains("POST"))
{
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
}
```

...and renamed it  GetOrPostRESTData()

But that violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

Yet, if I make it into two methods, with the POST method the same as the GET method, with the exception of the additional two lines of code that are otherwise in the conditional  ("if Post"), I am violating DRY, as most of the code is the same.

Is there a third way? A middle way? Or must I choose between these two violations? I am stuck between a DRY and a SOLID place.

Comment: Have a method that detects either POST or not and *that* would call one of two other methds.

Comment: You can always refactor the code they both use.

Comment: You could also split your current code into two methods; Call your first snippet (but without the if) POST and the other one GET with only the if condition followed by a call to POST. If you can't do that, usually you try to follow DRY, it's the essence of programming. And by the way there's a Stack Exchange website dedicated to [code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about looking at it from a higher level of abstraction? Instead of worrying about whether it's a `GET` or `POST` in the method name, just call it something like `ProcessRequest`. In that case, you could argue that the SRP is still being followed - the single thing your method is doing is processing the request indicated in the given URI - and you aren't duplicating any code.

Comment: Yes, single responsibility speaks about purpose not the process by which that purpose is accomplished which might require an if statement.

Comment: In this case though, do you not this that a `ProcessRequest` class is doing too much? — Even at a high level of abstraction, I would generally see CRUD operations as being single responsibilities individually, rather than collectively.